# Are there lockers or luggage storage facilities at the Bruxelles-Midi station?

Tags: trains, luggage-storage, brussels

I am travelling from Paris to Cologne with a one-day stopover in Brussels.  Where can I store luggage at the Bruxelles-Midi station?

Answer (score 8):

There are automatic luggage lockers and a staffed left-luggage service at the Bruxelles-Midi station. They are available 24h per day. When you arrive at the station go downstairs to the main hall and follow the signs. They are near the Eurostar check-in and Thalys reception.

http://www.belgianrail.be/en/stations-and-train/search-a-station/1/bruxelles-midi.aspx